# Meteor Error Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'

Tags: jquery, exception, meteor, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use a jquery plugin (Camera http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) that does some messing with the DOM after it is constructed (I call it in `Template.mytemplate.rendered`) but that's to be expected. The architecture of this app is that it has a number of photo galleries that are reached via iron router. As a result, I re-render the portion of the page with the image `div`s on each navigation click.

I don't expect Blaze to be a mind reader and figure out what I might have done to screw up the DOM behind the covers. Really what I'm looking for is how to explain to Blaze not to remove the old stuff but to remove the new stuff that appeared as a result of this jQuery plugin.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how exactly you planning to controll the lifecycle of the DOM elements?

Comment: The DOM is constructed initially from scratch, by default from this photo template using a specific layout. When a user clicks on link, iron router redoes the database query and renders the parts of the template necessary (not the layout, but the inner elements that contain the photos). So the lifecycle is from initial page load until iron router directs it to rebuild itself. The control of these elements is left to Meteor's reactive re-render and then to the jQuery plugin in the `rendered` callback.

Comment: I had a similar problem once and I ended up giving up on reactivity and handeled the rendering manually with `Blaze.renderWithData` and `Blaze.remove`. Look [here](https://github.com/anticoders/blog/blob/master/client/views/blogPostEdit.js) for an example.